# Split data frame to many

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data frame (**total of 72 columns**) that contains a few descriptors, some independent variables and some response variables as shown below,

```
data = {'description1':  ['first_value', 'second_value'],
        'description2': ['first_value', 'second_value'],
         'Ind_var':['first_value', 'second_value'],
         'Ind_var1':['first_value', 'second_value'],
         'Ind_var2':['first_value', 'second_value'],
         'Response1':['first_value', 'second_value'],
         'Response2':['first_value', 'second_value'],
         'Response3':['first_value', 'second_value']
        }

d0 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

My goal is to split them and create **three different data frames, one for every response variable**. At the end, I would like to get a list where each element is a data frame, i.e.

```
d1 = d0[['description1', 'description2', 'Ind_var', 'Ind_var1', 'Ind_var2', 'Response1']]
d2 = d0[['description1', 'description2', 'Ind_var', 'Ind_var1', 'Ind_var2', 'Response2']]
d3 = d0[['description1', 'description2', 'Ind_var', 'Ind_var1', 'Ind_var2', 'Response3']]
df_list = [d1, d2, d3]
```

I did this in `R`, as follows,

```
l1 <- split.default(full_df, 
                    c(rep('Conditions', 4), 
                      rep('Dependent', 7), 
                      rep('Independent', ncol(full_df)-11)))

l2 <- lapply(l1$Dependent, function(i) data.frame(l1$Independent, i))
```

Comment: I didn't understand what rule(s) you want to use to dictate the split on (because I have no idea what your R sample does), could you precise that ?

Comment: I want to split based on the response variable. So 1 data frame has all the descriptors and independent variables plus RESPONSE1. The second dataframe all descriptors and independent variables again plus RESPONSE 2, and so on. So all data frames will have all descriptors and independent vars but only one Response var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the columns you want to split are the columns 4 to 11 in df.columns

```py
cols = df.columns.difference(df.columns[4:11]).to_list()
dfs = [df0[cols + [col]] for col in df.columns[4:11]]
```

`cols` is a list of the names of the columns you *always* want to keep. The following line creates a list (using [list comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/list_comprehension.html)) of dataframes, selecting 1 dataframe for every column containing "Response" in its name.

Every dataframe will contain the `cols` columns, plus exactly 1 column containing `"Response"`.

If `df.columns[4:11]` doesn't return the columns you want, swapping the slicing (the `[4:11]` part) will work the same way.

Comment: I have 72 columns. Any way to get the column names dynamically?

Comment: This is where it gets tricky. If your column names are predictable (if these names follow rules), yes, you can. This sample code actually does : `filter(lambda x: "Response" in x, df0.columns)` dynamically gets all column names containing "Response". If you cannot know beforehands what name will the columns have, I'm afraid not much can be done.

Comment: If names are predictable but may vary, then it's probably best to refacto this sample code into a function (which I can do if you provide more information regarding column names & which to split on)

Comment: How about with index? The order is always the same: 4 condition vars, then 7 Response and the rest are independent

Comment: How should dfs be split regarding condition vars (if they do at all) ? I'll refacto my answer to use positional columns instead, since it fits (much) better.

Comment: They don't. Only response variables are used for the splitting. All the other columns stay as are

Comment: Then it is done, I am not sure whether R indexes start at 0 or 1 for columns, so be wary of that, but if your response columns are those that come out when doing `df.columns[4:11]` this should work fine. The previous probably worked too, but it was less elegant.

Comment: R starts from 1. I get this error though here: `KeyError: "None of [Index([('Atomic NumberGlucose conversion (%)', 'Atomic Radius (pm)Glucose conversion (%)', 'BlockGlucose conversion (%)', 'Brinell Hardness (MPa)Glucose conversion (%)', 'Bulk Modulus (GPa)Glucose conversion (%)', 'CatalystGlucose conversion (%)', 'Crystal StructureGlucose conversion (%)', 'Electrical Conductivity (S/m)Glucose conversion (%)', 'Electron Affinity (kJ/mol)Glucose conversion (%)', 'ElementGlucose conversion (%)', '..."`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244397/discussion-between-user12932966-and-sotos).

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the `response` column names consistently begin with `Response`, you can easily split the columns:

```
resps = [i for i in d0.columns if i.startswith('Response')]
commons = [i for i in d0.columns if not i.startswith('Response')]
```

From that it is trivial to build a list of dataframes, or a dictionnary indexed by the response:

```
framelist = [d0[commons + [i]] for i in resps]
```

or

```
framedict = {i: d0[commons + [i]] for i in resps}
```